# Looking for "stock_value" in a HTML page - preg_match stuff

Tags: php, preg-match-all

I have a URL of a HTML page that shows few products (pens, tshirts, etc), with stocks (products in warehouse).

I need to get (steal) the stock for a particular SKU_CODE corresponding to a product, since I've spoken via email with them and they don't have a .CSV / .TXT or Excel file with stocks.
So I need to load HTML from a dynamic URL and parse it with preg_match_all to get the external stock, and then display it on my website page, corresponding to a particular product.

It's similar to getting the current currency parity from a bank site, when you need to put it on your website, if you code it by hand.

So here it is, my code, which works only half. I managed to locate the SKU_CODE on the page, but when I look for the stock value, it shows Array() if i do a print_r and then i cannot get a hold on any value of that array. I'll post my code below.

$code = 'AP731463-10';
    $code_minimized = explode("-", $code);

```
$url_to_get = 'http://www.andapresent.hu/index.php?term_idk_list=4776829&term_idk_l=&filt=&qs='.$code_minimized[0].'';

function findinside($start, $end, $string) {
    preg_match_all('/' . preg_quote($start, '/') . '([^\.)]+)'. preg_quote($end, '/').'/i', $string, $m);
    return $m[1];
}


    $array_lines = file($url_to_get);
    //echo($array_lines[1654]);

    $cont = 0;
    $found_match = 0;

    while(isset($array_lines[$cont])){

        //daca inca nu s-a gasit codul cautat, cauta-l intre <b> </b>
        //if code we're looking for is not yet found, search between <b> </b>

        if($found_match==0){
            $out = findinside('<b>','</b>', $array_lines[$cont]);
        }

        //o data ce s-a gasit, flag set ca sa nu-l mai caute inca o data
        //once found, set flag $found_match so it will not look for it next time
        if($out[0]==$code && $found_match==0){
            $found_match = 1;
            echo "Found match : ".$code." = ".$out[0]."<br>";
        }

        //daca e flag-ul gasit e setat, cauta next info (stock-ul) pana il gaseste in $array_lines[$cont]
        //if flag is already set, look for next info (the stock value of the product)
        if($found_match==1){
            $out_2 = findinside('<td class="szoveg_k" align="center">','</td>', $array_lines[$cont]);
            echo $out_2;
        }


        $cont++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reading the HTML page line by line and searching one line at a time. But what if the open `<td>` and the closing `</td>` you are looking for appear on different lines? I think this is why your function does not return the correct result.

However, given the task you have I think it would be much more appropriate to search for the stock value using XPpath. Take a look at this [tutorial](http://martinsikora.com/parsing-html-pages-using-xpath) and see if it helps!